# Automatically adjusting map labels

Tags: r, rgdal

I'm using `rgdal` in `R` to generate a map of Minnesota at the county level, except that counties which are part of MSAs or micropolitan statistical areas are merged into one:

[image]

However, it's a bit unwieldy as some of the labels overlap. Is there any easy way to lessen this problem? I can think of some solutions, but most seem to be manual. Here is my current code:

```
library(rgdal)
library(GISTools)

mn_MSA <- readOGR(".", "mn_cbsa")
plot(mn_MSA)


numObs <- dim(mn_MSA@data)[1]
mylist <- c(1:numObs)

for (item in mylist) {
  text(coordinates(mn_MSA)[item, ][1], coordinates(mn_MSA)[item, ][2], mn_MSA$NAME[item], cex = 0.5)
}
```

Comment: `maptools::pointLabel(coordinates(mn_MSA), labels = mn_MSA$NAME)` which tries to avoid overlapping may help you a bit. Unfortunately it can accept your control on cex parameter (text size) only, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sample code.

```
library(raster)  # to download counties data
counties <- getData(name="GADM", country="USA", level=2)
min_counties <- subset(counties, NAME_1=="Minnesota")

library(maptools)  # to plot and label
plot(min_counties, xlim = c(-95, -90), ylim = c(43.5, 49.5), axes = FALSE)
pointLabel(coordinates(min_counties), labels = min_counties$NAME_2, col= 2, cex = 0.5)
```

And a captured image of southerh half of the plot to see how **maptools::pointLabel()** tries not to overlap labels.

[image]